# Hibernate Envers - audit multiple entities together

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I'm looking to use Envers to handle audits in my application.  I have multiple use cases, so I am limited to ensuring that I have a single `RevisionEntity` that represents my whole application in play (otherwise, I think the solution to this would be much easier with multiple entities).  Basically, i want to track multiple instances of an entity as a part of the same revision, and ideally even other entities as a part of that revision.

Basically, the insert of one entity (the parent) should trigger the start of the revision, updates to one entity should be included and inserts or updates to a third entity should also be included (in this one revision).

So does this require a custom strategy? Am I going to break the strategy of my existing entities or do I need to have an if/else check?

Answer (score 0):

Each revision captures the changes done in a single transaction and that isn't customizable; also there's always a single revision entity.

The idea is that the database is in a "consistent" state always before a transaction and after a transaction is commited. And that's the state that Envers wants to capture.

So if you modify multiple entities in one transaction, they will all be captured in a single revision.